# matplotlib, conda and cycler

Tags: matplotlib, virtualenv, conda

I just installed Anaconda 4.3.23 with Python 3 64 bit. I created virtual environment and installed `conda install matplotlib`. When I execute `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` I get back the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2d703b067d13> in <module>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import tensorflow as tf
----> 4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>()
    122 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
    123 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
--> 124 from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
    125                                 validate_backend,
    126                                 cycler)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py in <module>()
     35 
     36 # Don't let the original cycler collide with our validating cycler
---> 37 from cycler import Cycler, cycler as ccycler
     38 
     39 # interactive_bk = ['gtk', 'gtkagg', 'gtkcairo', 'qt4agg',

ImportError: No module named 'cycler'
```

I tried running `conda install cycler`, but got back:

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow:
#
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0    conda-forge
```

I ran all above under newly created virtual environment `tensorflow`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I had the exact same problem. ``conda install -c anaconda cycler`` worked for me.

Comment: @VincentLous Thank you, do you know what exactly `-c anadonda` does?

Comment: I do not have a clue

Comment: `-c anaconda` specifies the _channel_ (a name to url mapping) where anaconda searches for the package. [See the `conda install` documentation](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html). I'm not clear on where the channel urls are actually mapped, but I think `anaconda` references the packages you would find [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda).